# Can't delete FormRecognizer Resource on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I get the following error when I try to delete the [FormRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) Resource (currently in Preview). Deleting its resource group also failed for the same reason. Any ideas how to force-delete the resource?

The problem is that I am only allowed to create one FormRecognizer resource at a time and this one has become unusable but is still there and prevents the creation of a new one.

```
Executed delete command on 1 selected resources
Succeeded: 0, Failed: 1, Canceled: 0.
Error details
test_form_recognizer: Cannot modify resource with id 
'/subscriptions/[..]/resourceGroups/[..]/providers/
Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/test_form_recognizer'
 because the resource entity provisioning state is
 not terminal. Please wait for the provisioning state
 to become terminal and then retry the request. 
(Code: RequestConflict)
```

Comment: I tried to delete the resource manually using the CLI, `az resource delete` and `az group delete` but got the same error again. At some point the resource disappeared. The most likely explanation is that deletion was ultimately successful despite the error message and took 30-60 min.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this happens again, the typical solution here would be to clear the browser cache + sockets and wait for the TTL to expire, use another browser, or use a completely different system and then login to the Azure Portal again.